# Scala Lift JSON error that is not fixed with normal solution

Tags: scala, implicit, lift-json

I have the [following Scala project](https://github.com/hotmeatballsoup/intellij-scala-gradle-example) on GitHub. In that repo I have a class, [`Configurator`](https://github.com/hotmeatballsoup/intellij-scala-gradle-example/blob/master/shared/src/main/scala/com/me/myapp/Configurator.scala), whose job it is to read a JSON file's contents into a string, and then use the Lift JSON library to deserialize the string into an instance of an `AppConfig`:

```
import scala.io.Source
import net.liftweb.json._

class Configurator {
  def loadConfigs(configFileUri : String) : AppConfig = {
    implicit val formats = net.liftweb.json.DefaultFormats
    parse(Source.fromFile(configFileUri).mkString).extract[AppConfig]
  }
}
```

If you clone this and then run `./gradlew run` you'll get the following exception:

```
/Users/myuser/intellij-scala-gradle-example/shared/src/main/scala/com/me/myapp/Configurator.scala:9: could not find implicit value for parameter formats: net.liftweb.json.Formats
    parse(Source.fromFile(configFileUri).mkString).extract[AppConfig]
```

If you Google that exception you'll see 10,000 recommendations for that `implicit` format fix which I implemented right [here](https://github.com/hotmeatballsoup/intellij-scala-gradle-example/blob/master/shared/src/main/scala/com/me/myapp/Configurator.scala#L8). But that did not work for me. So I'm wondering:

1. Why am I seeing this exception?
2. What's the fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switched from Lift JSON to GSON and all my problems are gone.